# Usage of filter_path with helpers.scan in elastisearch client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

When doing a search operation in elasticsearch i want the metadata to be filtered out and return only "_source" in the response. I'm able to achieve the same through "search" in the following way:

> out1 = es.search(index='index.com', filter_path=['hits.hits._id',
>   'hits.hits._source'])

But when i do the same with scan method it just returns an empty list:

> out2 = helpers.scan(es, query, index='index.com',
>   doc_type='2016-07-27',filter_path= ['hits.hits._source'])

The problem may be with the way i'm processing the response of 'scan' method or with the way i'm passing the value to filter_path. To check the output i parse out2 to a list.

Comment: Upvoted the question as I found my answer in your question, thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scan` helper currently doesn't allow passing extra parameters to the `scroll` API so your `filter_path` doesn't apply to it. It does, however, get applied to the initial `search` API call which is used to initiate the `scan/scroll` cycle. This means that the `scroll_id` is stripped from the response causing the entire operation to fail.

In your case even passing the `filter_path` parameter to the `scroll` API calls would cause the helper to fail because it would strip the `scroll_id` which is needed for this operation to work and also because the helper relies on the structure of the response.

My recommendation would be to use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) if you need to limit the size of the response or use smaller `size` parameter than the default `1000`.

Hope this helps,
Honza

Answer (score 5):

You could pass `filter_path=['_scroll_id', '_shards', 'hits.hits._source']` to the scan helper to get it to work. Obviously that leaves some metadata in the response but it removes as much as possible while allowing the `scroll` to work. `_shards` is required because it is used internally by the scan helper.